# Open a Globally Defined Database by ReplicaID in a LotusScript Class

Tags: class, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a LS Class in as Library and the class works fine except now I need to open the database by replicaID. I have done this in other cases in an LS Library using the method below but the line :

```
Dim tDB As New NotesDatabase(serverName , LogRepID)
```

Does not actually open the database so when I set the Global logDB = tDB it is not opened and the script fails. LogRepID is the correct Replica ID and I did essentially the same open process in a simple LS Library without problems.

```
Class AgentLog
    AutoSave As Integer
    Enabled As Integer
    LogDoc As NotesDocument
    LogItem As NotesRichTextItem
    LogDB As NotesDatabase
    LogRepID As String
    LogStyle As NotesRichTextStyle
    DefaultStyle As NotesRichTextStyle
    ViewIcon As Integer
    Errors As Integer
    mainDB As NotesDatabase
    serverName As String
    vwApplication As NotesView
    appDoc As NotesDocument
    Sub New(Process As String, pAutoSave, pEnabled)
        Enabled = Cint(pEnabled)
        If Enabled Then
            Dim S As New NotesSession
            Set mainDB = S.CurrentDatabase
            serverName = mainDB.Server
            Set vwApplication = mainDB.getView("vwWFSApplicationsEnabled")
            Set appDoc = vwApplication.Getdocumentbykey("Admin", True)
            LogRepID = appDoc.Getitemvalue("agentLogRepID")(0)
            Dim tDB As New NotesDatabase(serverName , LogRepID)
            Set LogDB = tDB
            If LogDB.IsOpen Then
                Set LogDoc = LogDB.CreateDocument()
                Call LogDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "frmWFSAgentLog")
```

Solution:

Changed the code to:

```
Dim tDB As New NotesDatabase("" , "")
tDB.Openbyreplicaid ServerName , LogRepID
Set LogDB = tDB
```

and now it works not sure if this is the best way, but it works.

Comment: Did you try If Not isOpen(tDB) Then \n Call tDB.Open() \n End If?

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to go. Take a look at the example from the help of the Domino Designer:

```
Dim db As New NotesDatabase( "", "" )
If db.OpenByReplicaID( "Moscow", "85255FA900747B84" ) Then
  Print( db.Title & " was successfully opened" )
Else
  Print( "Unable to open database" )
End If
```